# team foundation server build variable for capture build error

Tags: tfs, build, tags

In my team foundation servers build definition I am trying to create a work item upon build failure and trying to create tags using "system.tags" but here I am trying to assign the reason for build failure as a tag to the work item. Here my question was, is there any predefined variable that capture why build is failed??

Comment: What's the version of TFS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

No such a predefined variable that is used to capture build errors. See [Build variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch#predefined-variables) for details.

If you are using vNext build (TFS 2015 or later version), In your scenario you can try below steps to add tags to specific work item:

1. Enable `Create Work Item on Failure` in build definition
2. Get the build errors (why build is failed) from build logs via web
   portal or with the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#logs).
3. Update the work item to add the failed reason as a tag with REST API
   (See [Add a tag](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#add-a-tag)).

e.g.:

```
PATCH: http://SERVER:8080/tfs/Collection/_apis/wit/workitems/223?api-version=1.0
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Tags",
    "value": "reason1; reason2"
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: @Krishna Is that helpful for you? any update? If that helpful, you can vote it up and if that resolved the isuee, you could Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.